# Missing properties in React Typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**React component**

```
import {Input} from '@xxx/forms';
<Input  label="account Name" name="account"/>
```

**input.d.ts**

```
import React, { Ref } from 'react';
import { InputProps as UITKInputProps } from '@xxx/input';
import { WithStyles, Density } from '@xxx/theme';
import { FormFieldProps as FormFieldPropsType } from '../FormField';
import { NecessityStyle } from '../types';
import styles from './styles';
export declare type InputProps = WithStyles<typeof styles> & UITKInputProps & {
    name: string;
    label?: string;
    id?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    FormFieldProps?: Omit<FormFieldPropsType, 'children' | 'name' | 'label'>;
    required?: boolean;
    necessityStyle?: NecessityStyle;
    helperText?: string;
    ref?: Ref<any>;
    fullWidth?: boolean;
    density?: Density;
};
declare const StyledInput: React.ComponentType<Pick<React.PropsWithChildren<InputProps>, "required" | "disabled" | "error" | "hidden" | "dir" | "label" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "color" | "ref" | "children" | "onBlur" | "onChange" | "onSubmit" | "name" | "onFocus" | "defaultValue" | "id" | "textAlign" | "translate" | "margin" | "className" | "innerRef" | "defaultChecked" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | "accessKey" | "contentEditable" | "contextMenu" | "draggable" | "lang" | "placeholder" | "spellCheck" | "tabIndex" | "radioGroup" | "role" | "about" | "datatype" | "inlist" | "prefix" | "property" | "resource" | "typeof" | "vocab" | "autoCapitalize" | "autoCorrect" | "autoSave" | "itemProp" | "itemScope" | "itemType" | "itemID" | "itemRef" | "results" | "security" | "unselectable" | "inputMode" | "is" | "aria-activedescendant" | "aria-atomic" | "aria-autocomplete" | "aria-busy" | "aria-checked" | "aria-colcount" | "aria-colindex" | "aria-colspan" | "aria-controls" | "aria-current" | "aria-describedby" | "aria-details" | "aria-disabled" | "aria-dropeffect" | "aria-errormessage" | "aria-expanded" | "aria-flowto" | "aria-grabbed" | "aria-haspopup" | "aria-hidden" | "aria-invalid" | "aria-keyshortcuts" | "aria-label" | "aria-labelledby" | "aria-level" | "aria-live" | "aria-modal" | "aria-multiline" | "aria-multiselectable" | "aria-orientation" | "aria-owns" | "aria-placeholder" | "aria-posinset" | "aria-pressed" | "aria-readonly" | "aria-relevant" | "aria-required" | "aria-roledescription" | "aria-rowcount" | "aria-rowindex" | "aria-rowspan" | "aria-selected" | "aria-setsize" | "aria-sort" | "aria-valuemax" | "aria-valuemin" | "aria-valuenow" | "aria-valuetext" | "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" | "onCopy" | "onCopyCapture" | "onCut" | "onCutCapture" | "onPaste" | "onPasteCapture" | "onCompositionEnd" | "onCompositionEndCapture" | "onCompositionStart" | "onCompositionStartCapture" | "onCompositionUpdate" | "onCompositionUpdateCapture" | "onFocusCapture" | "onBlurCapture" | "onChangeCapture" | "onBeforeInput" | "onBeforeInputCapture" | "onInput" | "onInputCapture" | "onReset" | "onResetCapture" | "onSubmitCapture" | "onInvalid" | "onInvalidCapture" | "onLoad" | "onLoadCapture" | "onError" | "onErrorCapture" | "onKeyDown" | "onKeyDownCapture" | "onKeyPress" | "onKeyPressCapture" | "onKeyUp" | "onKeyUpCapture" | "onAbort" | "onAbortCapture" | "onCanPlay" | "onCanPlayCapture" | "onCanPlayThrough" | "onCanPlayThroughCapture" | "onDurationChange" | "onDurationChangeCapture" | "onEmptied" | "onEmptiedCapture" | "onEncrypted" | "onEncryptedCapture" | "onEnded" | "onEndedCapture" | "onLoadedData" | "onLoadedDataCapture" | "onLoadedMetadata" | "onLoadedMetadataCapture" | "onLoadStart" | "onLoadStartCapture" | "onPause" | "onPauseCapture" | "onPlay" | "onPlayCapture" | "onPlaying" | "onPlayingCapture" | "onProgress" | "onProgressCapture" | "onRateChange" | "onRateChangeCapture" | "onSeeked" | "onSeekedCapture" | "onSeeking" | "onSeekingCapture" | "onStalled" | "onStalledCapture" | "onSuspend" | "onSuspendCapture" | "onTimeUpdate" | "onTimeUpdateCapture" | "onVolumeChange" | "onVolumeChangeCapture" | "onWaiting" | "onWaitingCapture" | "onAuxClick" | "onAuxClickCapture" | "onClick" | "onClickCapture" | "onContextMenu" | "onContextMenuCapture" | "onDoubleClick" | "onDoubleClickCapture" | "onDrag" | "onDragCapture" | "onDragEnd" | "onDragEndCapture" | "onDragEnter" | "onDragEnterCapture" | "onDragExit" | "onDragExitCapture" | "onDragLeave" | "onDragLeaveCapture" | "onDragOver" | "onDragOverCapture" | "onDragStart" | "onDragStartCapture" | "onDrop" | "onDropCapture" | "onMouseDown" | "onMouseDownCapture" | "onMouseEnter" | "onMouseLeave" | "onMouseMove" | "onMouseMoveCapture" | "onMouseOut" | "onMouseOutCapture" | "onMouseOver" | "onMouseOverCapture" | "onMouseUp" | "onMouseUpCapture" | "onSelect" | "onSelectCapture" | "onTouchCancel" | "onTouchCancelCapture" | "onTouchEnd" | "onTouchEndCapture" | "onTouchMove" | "onTouchMoveCapture" | "onTouchStart" | "onTouchStartCapture" | "onPointerDown" | "onPointerDownCapture" | "onPointerMove" | "onPointerMoveCapture" | "onPointerUp" | "onPointerUpCapture" | "onPointerCancel" | "onPointerCancelCapture" | "onPointerEnter" | "onPointerEnterCapture" | "onPointerLeave" | "onPointerLeaveCapture" | "onPointerOver" | "onPointerOverCapture" | "onPointerOut" | "onPointerOutCapture" | "onGotPointerCapture" | "onGotPointerCaptureCapture" | "onLostPointerCapture" | "onLostPointerCaptureCapture" | "onScroll" | "onScrollCapture" | "onWheel" | "onWheelCapture" | "onAnimationStart" | "onAnimationStartCapture" | "onAnimationEnd" | "onAnimationEndCapture" | "onAnimationIteration" | "onAnimationIterationCapture" | "onTransitionEnd" | "onTransitionEndCapture" | "type" | "fullWidth" | "autoFocus" | "value" | "inputProps" | "inputRef" | "readOnly" | "multiline" | "autoComplete" | "endAdornment" | "inputComponent" | "renderSuffix" | "rows" | "rowsMax" | "rowsMin" | "startAdornment" | "disableUnderline" | "density" | "necessityStyle" | "helperText" | "cursorPositionOnFocus" | "emptyReadOnlyMarker" | "highlightOnFocus" | "FormFieldProps"> & import("@material-ui/styles").StyledComponentProps<"disabled" | "input" | "root" | "readOnly" | "focused" | "multiline" | "inputMultiline" | "endAdornment" | "startAdornment" | "lowDensity" | "touchDensity" | "mediumDensity" | "highDensity" | "field">>;
export { StyledInput as Input };
```

The only required field for `<Input />` is `name`. However, the compiler is complaining:

*Type '{ name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<PropsWithChildren, "ref" | "label" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "onBlur" | "onChange" | "onSubmit" | "autoComplete" | ... 276 mo
re ... | "FormFieldProps">': slot, style, title, onBlur, and 267 more.*

***How can I declare Input component inside my component?***

Comment: I'm not understand what's going on in your component....is `import {Input} from '@xxx/forms'` from an external library, or your own package?  Where is this .d.ts file coming from?  What is actually happening in your component?  All you posted was the import and the line `<Input  label="account Name" name="account"/>`...?

Answer (score 0):

While you didn't provide full type definitions for `WithStyles` and `UITKInputProps` I'd guess they are having *a lot* of required props inside. So your `InputProps` type gets expanded into a huge list of required props from those two types **plus** explicitly defined props with a required `name` field. Thus the error.

If you want your `InputProps` type to have the only required field `name` you may define it as:

```ts
export declare type InputProps 
  = Partial<WithStyles<typeof styles>>
  & Partial<UITKInputProps> 
  & {
        name: string;
        label?: string;
        id?: string;
        disabled?: boolean;
        FormFieldProps?: Omit<FormFieldPropsType, 'children' | 'name' | 'label'>;
        required?: boolean;
        necessityStyle?: NecessityStyle;
        helperText?: string;
        ref?: Ref<any>;
        fullWidth?: boolean;
        density?: Density;
    };
```